# Squarespace access JSON properties via URL?

Tags: json, squarespace

I know that I can access the JSON data like so http://base-template.squarespace.com/news/?format=json-pretty. But what I want to access lets says a property on that like news.items? http://base-template.squarespace.com/news/items/?format=json-pretty throw an error. Is there a way to drill into the JSON data via the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access a collection's items using the same `format=json-pretty` query parameter as you mentioned.

Do note, however, that:

1. The URL must exist (which in your second 'news' example is not the case)
2. To get a list of items from a collection, you use the `format=json-pretty` on the collection, the scope into `items` from there.
3. When performing this type of request via Javascript, you'll probably want to simply use `format=json` since the 'pretty' line breaks and indenting aren't necessary in that case.

For example, using the base-template as you have already mentioned, to get the blog items you would use: `https://base-template.squarespace.com/blog?format=json-pretty`. Within the JSON, you'll see an 'items' array, which is the data you're looking for (See the image below for a screenshot of this.). If that website had a "/news" collection, you could do similar.

Similarly, if you wanted to view the JSON output from a specific item, you would, for example, use: `https://base-template.squarespace.com/blog/2016/7/15/most-recent-sample-blog-post?format=json-pretty`

[image]